# Do I need a visa for Italy if I have a Romanian residence permit?

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, filipino-citizens

I am a Filipina and I live in Romania. My cousin, who lives in Italy, wants me to come visit her for three days. I have a residence permit valid for one year in Romania. It’s not a working permit; it’s an “other purpose” permit.

I want to know if I need a visa for Italy. I asked immigration here in Romania, and they said I don’t need a visa and I can go with this permit to Italy for 60 days. But I want to be sure if I need one or not.

Comment: Do you have a family member who is an EU or EFTA citizen? If so, do you have a family member residence card?

Comment: Why would you not trust the immigration guys and ask random folks on internet?

Comment: @HankyPanky OP asked Romanian immigration officers about Italian immigration requirements; they are probably not trained in that, which would explain why they gave incorrect information.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=PH&AR=RO&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=IT&selDest=Italy&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=PEARL&subuser=PEARL), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a family member
>   residence card issued by Romania. The card must be issued to family members of a national of Switzerland or an EEA Member State. They are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days and must travel with or travel to join the national of Switzerland or EEA Member State. **This does not apply to passengers with a different type of residence permit.**

So unless you have a family member who is an EU or EFTA **citizen**, and were issued a family member residence card, you **do** need a visa